# Does "brew install gcc" installs GNU C++ compiler on macOS?

Tags: homebrew, gcc

I am a new Mac user and was wondering if installing gcc via `brew install gcc` command would install GNU C++ compiler?

Comment: If you install XCode from the app store, you get gcc with it.

Comment: @WGroleau xcode does not provide gcc. It provides clang which is usually sufficient don't assume that gcc us the correct compiler to use.

Comment: Didn't know they changed it.  Used to be gcc.

Comment: @mmmmmm it provides both clang++ and gcc

and both of them are installed in this dir.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: @Vignesh Try running that gcc as `gcc --version` What does it print?

Comment: @mmmmmm It prints like this,

Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: @Vignesh well that  says it is  clang not gcc. Apple does NOT supply gcc you need to install gcc from a package manager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, installing `gcc` using `brew install gcc` will install GNU C++ compiler.

The compiler is installed by default in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin`.